# Record video raw from Tango with Tango Ros Streamer?

Tags: ros, google-project-tango

I want to record data from Tango with Tango Ros Streamer and save them into a bag by command:
rosbag record -a
When i visualize sequence of image in this bag, i realize the frame rate is extremely slow. 
Do you have any idea to modify or fix frame rate with this application?

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical wifi bandwidth is 11 megabits.

- One 1280x720 YUV image: 1280*720*1.5 = 1.3824 megabits
- One 24fps stream of these images: 24*1.3824 megabits = 33.18 megabits

So you cannot transmit the native stream of RGB images over WiFi.

That is why in the [source code of the Tango Ros Streamer app](https://github.com/Intermodalics/tango_ros/blob/df405afc01b66035f8805023b81caab1784f9836/tango_ros_common/tango_ros_native/test/test_tango_ros_msg.cpp) you will see

```
constexpr double COLOR_IMAGE_RATE = 8.; // in Hz.
```

You can either modify the code of this app to decrease the size of the images and increase the COLOR_IMAGE_RATE, either you want the full resolution and you can create an application which saves all the images on the device.